# updating query to read from Microsoft access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, ms-access-2013

hello guys i have problem with running update query from Microsoft access 2013 i just want to update client table with client id and name and phone i cant get the data to be update always error in syntax

```
string I = "UPDATE client SET client.ID =" + ID.Text + " ,client.Name =" + Name.Text + " ,client.Phone = " + Phone.Text + " WHERE client.ID="+ ID.Text +"";
            command.CommandText = I;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a parameterized query, like this:

```cs
string I = "UPDATE client SET client.Name = ?, client.Phone = ? WHERE client.ID = ?";
command.CommandText = I;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Name.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Phone.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ID.Text);
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that it makes no sense to "SET" client.ID since it is not going to change.